# Can't access member of RaycasHit

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

i am new in Unity just learning to build games . 
but i have a problem to access a member of RaycastHit object .

i am getting this error .

```
Assets/MeleeySystem.js(12,32): BCE0019: 'distance' is not a member of 'System.Type'.
```

it seems distance is not a member of RaycastHit.

Here is my code . if someone can help me what i am doing wrong in this .

```
var TheDamage : int = 50;
var Distance : float = 2.5;

function Update(){

 if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
    var hit = RaycastHit;
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, 10)){
        Distance = hit.distance;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var HitInfo : RaycastHit;
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, HitInfo, 10)){
    Distance = HitInfo.distance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare hit as RaycastHit:

```
RaycastHit hit = RaycastHit;
```

Or cast it to RaycastHit:

```
Distance = ((RaycastHit)hit).distance;
```

Not sure if this is correct UnityScript syntax.

Comment: thanks for pointing on the right place . but the solution is `var hit : RaycastHit`